# On complex integration

Tags: complex-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

The question given is to integrate:
$∫z^2e^{1/z}dz$ over the unit circle I managed to get 
$z^2e^{1/z}$ as $z^2 + \frac{z}{1!}+ \frac{1}{2!} +....$

However I fail to understand how to get the residues for the following can someone help me in this

Comment: Where does $e^{1\over z}$ have a singularity in $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Probably at z=0 ,which is a essential singularity

Comment: Exactly, which an essential singularity of $z^2e^{1\over z}$ with residue equal to the coeff of ${1\over z}$ in its Laurant expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you explain me how is the residue equal to coeff of 1/z in Laurent expansion rather than coeff of z=0

Comment: It actually comes from $$\oint_C {1\over z^n}dz=0$$ for $n\ne 1$ and $2\pi i $ for $n=1$. You can substitute the Laurant series of any function instead of itself to see the reason more clearly.

Comment: You should know this is *always* how you can find the residue. The residue of $f$ at $z=a$ is the coefficient of $\frac1{z-a}$ in the Laurent expansion of $f$ about $z=a$.